# Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

Debug show me that:

```
comments = Comment.get_for_intention(id)
```

is:

> {QuerySet} Unable to get repr for class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'

Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    intention = models.ForeignKey(Intention)
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

    @staticmethod
    def get_for_intention(intention_id):
        return Comment.objects.filter(intention=intention_id)[:10]
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Could someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is because of intention. it is foreign key and you want to use all intention object.

You should use

```
def get_fot_intention(self):
   return self.Intention.intention_id
```

if you want to take comments only you dont have to define get_fot_intention and you dont have to use intention_id , just use intention object. You can use this for example:

```
def intention_detail(request,slug=None):

    intention = get_object_or_404(Intention,slug=slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(intention=intention)
```

but you have to slug field in intention.

Comment: I want to get comments related to intention. Parameter id is intention id